Expected Value Chi Square distribution
I'm trying to simulate the distribution from the sample variance $s^2$ and compare it with the theoretical distribution.
Therefore, I perform a fairly simple simulation (upfront, I'm not a mathematician and I tried my very best to write down all mathematical notations as good as possible, but I'm pretty sure that there are some mistakes, so please correct me, I'm happy to learn):

$X$ is a random variable, sampled from the standard normal distribution: $X∼N(μ,σ^2)$ with $μ = 0$ and $σ^2 = 1$
Sample $n$-times getting $n$ observations
Calculate the sample variance $s^2$
Calculate the theoretical 2.5% and 97.5% quantiles (var_lower_qt_theo and var_upper_qt_theo) using the following inequality:
$\frac{(n−1)s^2}{\chi^2_{0.025,n-1}}<σ^2<\frac{(n−1)s^2}{\chi^2_{0.975,n-1}}$
In order to reproduce the results via a simulation and to generate a distribution for $σ^2$, I changed $\frac{(n−1)s^2}{\sigma^2}∼\chi^2_{n-1}$  to $\frac{(n−1)s^2}{\chi^2_{n-1}}∼\sigma^2$. Am I allowed to do this?
I sampled $m = 100,000$ times to reproduce the results from point 4 by using $\frac{(n−1)s^2}{Z}$, where $Z ∼ \chi^2_{n-1}$
Calculating the quantiles (var_lower_qt_sim and var_upper_qt_sim) and mean (mean_variance_sim) from these observations
Repeat 1-6 for $n$ with  $\{2,3,4,...,20\}$

The theoretical and simulated quantiles match together (except for some small deviations due to the sampling procedure)
However, calculating the mean from these simulated results does not give me back $s^2$, instead I get an estimator exactly $\frac{n-1}{n-3}$ bigger than $s^2$ for $n>3$. Can someone explain this systematic deviation? It seems that: $E(\frac{(n−1)s^2}{Z}) \neq \frac{(n−1)s^2}{E(Z)} = E(s^2)$
Obviously, I did something wrong. So, I thought maybe I need to change $\frac{(n−1)s^2}{\sigma^2}∼\chi^2$ to $\frac{\chi^2 \sigma^2}{n−1}∼s^2$ and repeat the steps 1-7 (However, here I would assume that the sample variance is the population variance, what is wrong again....). This time the mean of the simulated results (var_sim2 in the code) is identical to $s^2$, however the quantiles are wrong (not shown in the table). So it seems that I need to choose between the correct confidence intervals of sample variance or the correct expected value. I both cases, I wouldn't trust the simulated distribution.
Can someone explain these observations?
EDIT:
Question
To reduce all of this down to one specific topic. I'm looking for the distribution of the sample variance, which has the "correct" quantiles (e.g., contains in 95% of all cases the true population variance) and the "correct" expected value (e.g. expected value is equal to the sample variance)
Result Table:



n
sample_variance
mean variance_sim
quotient
var_lower_qt_sim
var_lower_qt_theo
var_upper_qt_sim
var_upper_qt_theo




2
1.396
84600.341
0.000
0.283
0.278
1401.237
1421.894


3
0.307
4.258
0.072
0.083
0.083
11.860
12.115


4
1.249
3.772
0.331
0.401
0.401
17.036
17.358


5
0.993
1.970
0.504
0.357
0.357
8.089
8.201


6
0.286
0.476
0.600
0.111
0.111
1.720
1.720


7
1.115
1.673
0.667
0.464
0.463
5.347
5.408


8
1.396
1.953
0.715
0.613
0.610
5.800
5.782


9
0.955
1.274
0.749
0.434
0.436
3.502
3.504


10
0.382
0.493
0.776
0.181
0.181
1.280
1.274


11
1.626
2.035
0.799
0.795
0.794
5.002
5.007


12
1.301
1.594
0.816
0.653
0.653
3.754
3.751


13
0.731
0.877
0.834
0.374
0.376
1.972
1.991


14
1.285
1.516
0.847
0.677
0.675
3.339
3.335


15
0.744
0.868
0.857
0.400
0.399
1.858
1.850


16
1.536
1.771
0.867
0.839
0.838
3.673
3.679


17
1.334
1.526
0.874
0.742
0.740
3.095
3.089


18
1.668
1.892
0.881
0.939
0.939
3.747
3.748


19
0.854
0.960
0.889
0.487
0.487
1.876
1.867


20
0.955
1.068
0.895
0.551
0.552
2.042
2.037




set.seed(09062024)
sample_var <- NULL
theo_qt_upper <- NULL
theo_qt_lower <- NULL
var_qt_lower <- NULL
var_qt_upper <- NULL
var_mean <- NULL
theo_mean <- NULL
var_mean2 <- NULL
var_sim2 <- NULL

n <- seq(2,20,1)
sd <- 1


for(i in 1:length(n)){
x <- rnorm(n = n[i], 0,sd)
sample_var[i] <- var(x)
var_sim <- (n[i]-1)*sample_var[i]/rchisq(n = 100000, df = n[i]-1)
var_sim2 <- (rchisq(n = 100000, df = n[i]-1)*sample_var[i])/(n[i]-1)

var_qt_lower[i] <- quantile(var_sim, probs = 0.025)
var_qt_upper[i] <- quantile(var_sim, probs = 0.975)
theo_qt_upper[i] <- (n[i]-1)*sample_var[i]/qchisq(p = 0.025, df = n[i]-1)
theo_qt_lower[i] <- (n[i]-1)*sample_var[i]/qchisq(0.975, df = n[i]-1)
var_mean[i] <- mean(var_sim)
var_mean2[i] <- mean(var_sim2)
w <- dchisq(seq(1e-5,250,1e-3),df = n[i]-1)/sum(dchisq(seq(1e-5,250,1e-3),df = n[i]-1))
chi <- seq(1e-5,250,1e-3)

theo_mean[i] <- sum(((n[i]-1)*sample_var[i]/chi)*w)
}

df <- data.frame(n = n, 
           sample_variance = sample_var, 
           variance_sim = var_mean, 
           variance_sim2 = var_mean2,
           variance_theo_distr = theo_mean,
           quotient = sample_var/theo_mean,
           var_lower_qt_sim = var_qt_lower,
           var_lower_qt_theo = theo_qt_lower,
           var_upper_qt_sim = var_qt_upper,
           var_upper_qt_theo = theo_qt_upper)


Your (5) "I changed $\frac{(n−1)s^2}{\sigma^2}∼\chi^2_{n-1}$  to $\frac{(n−1)s^2}{\chi^2_{n-1}}∼\sigma^2$" does not make much sense as $\sigma^2$ does not have a distribution while your $(n-1)s^2$ and the associated value from $\chi^2_{n-1}$ should be dependent on each other.
Dividing $(n−1)s^2$ by an independent $Z\sim \chi^2_{n-1}$ will indeed give a different result.  $\frac 1Z$ has a so-called inverse-chi-squared distribution (I would prefer reciprocal-chi-squared distribution) and $E\left[\frac 1 Z\right]=\frac1{n-3}$ when $n>3$, which when multiplied by $(n-1)$ leads to your $\frac{n-1}{n-3}$ observation.
You asked for

the distribution of the sample variance, which has the "correct" quantiles (e.g., contains in 95% of all cases the true population variance) and the "correct" expected value (e.g. expected value is equal to the sample variance)

and again your final words are a little strange: it would make more sense to be looking for a distribution whose expected value is equal to the population variance if that is what is important to you.
You already have that at the start of your question when looking at $\frac{(n−1)s^2}{\sigma^2}∼\chi^2_{n-1}$ so $s^2$ has a scaled chi-square distribution with expectation $\sigma^2$, the same distribution as $\frac{\sigma^2}{(n-1)}Z$ if $Z\sim \chi^2_{n-1}$.
Your $\frac{(n−1)s^2}{\chi^2_{0.025,n-1}}$ and $\frac{(n−1)s^2}{\chi^2_{0.975,n-1}}$ are sensible endpoints for a $95\%$ confidence interval, though the former is the upper point and the latter the lower point while you have them the other way round - the reciprocal reverses the inequality.
Here is an R simulation illustrating this for $n=5, \mu=0, \sigma^2=1$ and $95\%$ confidence intervals, though all of those are easily adjusted if you wish:
samplevariance <- function(n, mu, sigmasq){
  X <- rnorm(n, mu, sqrt(sigmasq))
  Xbar <- sum(X) / n
  ssq <- sum((X - Xbar)^2) / (n-1)
  return(ssq)
  }

set.seed(2024)
n <- 5
mu <- 0
sigmasq <- 1
confidence <- 0.95
cases <- 10^6
simssq <- replicate(cases, samplevariance(n, mu, sigmasq))
upperci <- simssq * (n-1) / qchisq((1-confidence)/2, n-1)
lowerci <- simssq * (n-1) / qchisq((1+confidence)/2, n-1)
 
mean(simssq)                                # should be close to sigmasq
# 1.000121
mean(upperci > sigmasq & lowerci < sigmasq) # should be close to confidence 
# 0.949927

which is what you are asking for, allowing for simulation noise.
We can plot the distribution of $s^2$ (in black below) and compare it to the theoretical scaled chi-square distribution (in red) to see the match.
plot(density(simssq))
curve(dchisq(x*(n-1)/sigmasq, n-1) * (n-1)/sigmasq, 
      from=0, to=6*sigmasq, col="red", add=TRUE) 


We can even see your $\frac{n-1}{n-3}$ result:
mean((n-1) * simssq / rchisq(cases, n-1))
# 1.995052
sigmasq * (n-1) / (n-3)
# 2


Thanks a lot for your detailed answer and also your explanations regarding my wrong mathematical notations! That already helped a lot!

Second comment (I was too slow with editing the first one)
My questions might sound strange, but I'm actually looking for the sample variance distribution. If I get confidence intervals and a maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) for s², I should also get a distribution for a sample variance. I thought that the MLE of s² for a sample is equal to the expected value of that sample variance, right? So, again instead of the population variance distribution, I'm looking for the sample variance distribution.

@Mexx My graph is the distribution of $s^2=\frac1{n-1}\sum (X_i-\bar X)^2$ - in this particular case assuming $n=5$ and  normal i.i.d. $X_i$ with $\sigma^2=1$.  $s^2$ is an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$ but is not a MLE of $\sigma^2$, though the slightly smaller $\frac1{n}\sum (X_i-\bar X)^2$ is an MLE of $\sigma^2$.  Your "the MLE of $s^2$ for a sample is equal to the expected value of that sample variance" again does not make much sense to me.

Sorry, I was not precise enough in my formulation and thanks for pointing that out. What I wanted to say is, in your simulation your repeatedly sample from the population with known µ and σ² and calculate s². I want to get the probability distribution of s² for one sample, when the true µ and σ² are not known.

Another thought. Was my initial simulation with the reciprocal-chi-squared distribution actually the distribution I am looking for? The simulated confidence intervals match the calculated confidence intervals for s² almost perfectly (see my result table). I just got unsure, because I couldn't find my initial point estimator for s² in this distribution anymore by averaging over all simulated values. However, as you pointed out, the expected value from a reciprocal-chi-squared distribution is 1/(n-3) and this would allow me to calculate from the distribution back to s² again.
